# jQuery multiply this.index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to write a simple jQuery function that will multiple the index of an object by 20 and assign that value as a CSS `top` to the object. So if there are 5 objects, the top would have a top value of 20, the second would have a value of 40, third would be set to 60, and so on. This is what I have:

```
$('ul.nav li').each(function(){
    var $n = $('ul.nav li').index(this);
    $(this).css('top', 20 * n );
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are declaring $n and using n

Comment: A javascript console is a good tool, it could notice that `n is undefined`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`index` is already provided by `$.each`:

```
$("ul.nav li").each(function(index){
  $(this).css( "top", 20 * ++index );
});
```

The problem with your code was that you were creatin `$n`, but *using* `n` (note the abandoned `$`).

You could also use implicit looping:

```
$("ul.nav li").css("top", function(i){
  return 20 * ++i;
});
```

Comment: According to the original question should be: `$(this).css("top", 20 * (index + 1) );`